# call to changeDetectorRef in angular 4 stops working after async call

Tags: angular

I have the following code in an angular component which is an event handler for the progress event of a file upload:

```ts
progressEvent(evt: TransferProgressEvent) {
  const percentage = evt.loadedBytes === 0 ? 0 : Math.ceil((evt.loadedBytes / this.control.controls.file.size) * 100);

  this.control.controls.progress.setValue(`${evt.loadedBytes}%`);

  this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

I am using `onPush` change detection, I have noticed some weird behaviour.

The event handler is called but the progress is not updated.

While debugging this I noticed that once I call an `async` functio, `this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` no longer works.

This code demonstrates this:

```ts
async upload(file: FileToUpload, options?: IUploadToBlockBlobOptions): Promise<UploadResponse> {
  const blobName = file.blobName;

  // THIS WILL CAUSE THE PROGRESS TO BE UPDATED
  file.progressEvent({ loadedBytes: 50 });

  const blockBlobURL = await this.getSasUrl(blobName);

  // NO UPDATE WILL HAPPEN AFTER ASYNC CALL
  file.progressEvent({ loadedBytes: 100 });
}
```

I am new to angular and I suspect this is something to do with angular zones.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what is happening here?

Comment: Does your promise in `getSasUrl` ever resolve?

Comment: yes, totally works, code completes fine just the progress not getting updated